# Mysql Query not showing all data

Tags: mysql

Query on multiple tables :

```
select * from bonlivraison,categorie,fourniture where bonlivraison.id_bl=fourniture.id_bl and fourniture.id_categorie=categorie.id_categorie
```

Result : 219 rows

Query on single table :

```
select * from fourniture
```

Result : 263 rows

i want the first query to get me the 263 rows

Comment: Hey there!

Can you provide more details on this? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show fourniture's table data and the result returned for the above query as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use left join and start with table `fourniture`

```
select * from fourniture 
left join categorie on fourniture.id_categorie=categorie.id_categorie 
left join  bonlivraison on bonlivraison.id_bl=fourniture.id_bl
```

Your query Shows only record from table bonlivraison which have related entries in both other tables.

Comment: it was an answer that help find where was the problem thank you